# Fetch the data from the drop down list in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, drop-down-menu

I want to fetch the data from the drop down list in the view,and the data is already in my mssql database.

There is a column named "Address",and I used the column value to filter the data in database to get what I want,and this is my code.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetPharmacy(string cityName, string areaName)
{
Project1Entities db = new Project1Entities();
var query = (from a in db.Pharmacies
where a.Adress == cityName
select a);
var query1 = (from b in query
where b.Adress == areaName
select b);
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(areaName))
{
return Json(new EmptyResult());
}
return Json(query1);
}
```

The "cityname" and "areaname" has value, but when I send the request to the database with the button in my view,it returns nothing...

Here is my function in ajex:

```
function SerchallData(selectedCity) {
            var selectedCity = $('#CITY option:selected').val();
            var selectedValue = $('#AREA option:selected').val();
            if ($.trim(selectedValue).length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetMaskmap", "Getarea")',
                    data: { cityName: selectedCity, areaName: selectedValue },
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#Table>tbody').empty();
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            var row = $('<tr><td>' + data[i].ID + '</td><td>' + data[i].Name + '</td><td>' + data[i].Adress + '</td><td>' +  data[i].Phonenumber +'</td></tr>');
                            $('#Table>tbody').append(row);
                            
                        }
                        
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
```

I wonder where is the problem that I could not get the value return from the database?

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't make sense. In the first part you request records that have an `Adress` equal to `cityName`. In the second part you filter that down to records, that have an `Adress` equal to `areaName`. If `cityName` and `areaName` are not equal, the result will always be empty.

As the sequential combination of two `Where` queries is equal to a single query with both conditions combined with a logical "AND", you can rewrite your request like this, which makes the mistake obvious:

```cs
var query = (from a in db.Pharmacies
   where a.Adress == cityName && a.Adress == areaName
   select a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one, you are not returning the object from the database, you are returning a query. Secondly that query doesn't make logical sense, I think you meant to select a value where the record matches either value.

Yry this:

```
var pharamacy = db.Pharmacies.Where(x=>x.Adress == cityName || x.Adress == areaName).FirstOrDefault();
```